# checking the contents of SCTLR

Tags: arm

I have come across the fact that Arm V7 ISA supports unaligned memory access for some load and store instructions and the    `A` bit in    `SCTLR` controls whether an alignment fault is raised when unaligned access is tried .I wanted to know what instruction can be used to write or read the    `SCTLR` .I found `MRS /MSR` will act only on `CPSR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Cortex-A9 TRM 4.3.9](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0388i/CIHFIAJC.html):

```
MRC p15, 0,<Rd>, c1, c0, 0; Read SCTLR
MCR p15, 0,<Rd>, c1, c0, 0; Write SCTLR
```

Additional notes:

- Attempts to read or write the SCTLR from secure or Non-secure User modes result in an Undefined Instruction exception.
- Attempts to write to this register in secure privileged mode when CP15SDISABLE is HIGH result in an Undefined Instruction exception.
- Attempts to write secure modify only bits in non-secure privileged modes are ignored.
- Attempts to read secure modify only bits return the secure bit value.
- Attempts to modify RO bits are ignored.

Comment: so `SCLTR` is a coprocessor ?

Comment: Just had a look at the link you provided , thanks for the answer